# Moduler, mountable route handlers in Suave?

Tags: suave

What's the recommended way to have mountable route handlers in Suave, as the [routers](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#express-router) in Express.js?

On a high level, what I want to achieve is a way to define my routings using the relative paths, and mount them under a parent path. E.g, I want to write a REST API with path handlers:

```
channel/ -> handle channel
users/ -> handle users
...
```

Then mount them under version 1 path `v1`, so that they are accessible with:

```
/v1/channel/
/v1/users/
```

In express.js, I can do this with the following code. How can I achieve something functionally similar in Suave? I understand Suave tackles the problem in a totally different fashion, but just wondering what's the approach Suave takes to solve this in a modular way.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var routerV1 = express
    .Router()
    .all('/:channel', (req, res) => {
        var channel = req.params.channel,
            msg = req.query.msg;

        var body = handleRequest(channel, msg);
        res.send(body);
    });

app.use('/v1', routerV1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Suave currently does not provide such a facility.

It should be easy to implement such a thing though; see for example the following blog post;

[Suave.IO vdir to run choose routes relative to a path](http://tech.edelste.in/post/91885205138/suaveio-vdir-to-run-choose-routes-relative-to-a)